# Let $a_n=f(1/n)$. Show that $a_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Let $f:(0,1] \mapsto \mathbf{R}$ be a differentiable function with $|f'|\le 1 \ \forall x\in (0,1]$. Let $a_n=f(1/n)$ be a sequence with $n \in \mathbf{N}$. Show that $a_n$ converges.

I know that there is a post with this question, but i would like to know if my approach is correct, please. In the other post, the MVT is used.

As $f'$ is bounded, $f$ is Lipschitz $\implies$ uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$. Thus, we have by definition that $\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists \delta>0 \ \forall x,y \in (0,1]$: $|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

To show that $a_n$ is convergent, we have to show that it is Cauchy: $\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists N \ \forall m,n\ge N:$ $|a_m-a_n|=|f(1/m)-f(1/n)|<\epsilon$.

As $1/m$ and $1/n$ are in $(0,1] \ \forall m,n$, we can apply the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous and so $a_n$ is Cauchy $\implies$ convergent.

I read the other post, but they applied the MVT to conclude. Is it necessary?

Comment: Also: the implication $f'$ bounded $\implies$ $f$ Lipschitz uses the mean value theorem as well, right? So your proof doesn't skip that either :)

Comment: @Lukas Miristwhisky Yes I'm agree that to show that implication we have to pass by MVT

Comment: Just a question : how do you prove that Lipschitz$\implies $ uniformly continuous without using MVT ?

Comment: @SurbAlright, thank you for the feedback. But, why the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous doesn't imply directly that $f(1/n)$ is Cauchy? As if the uniform continuity works $\forall x,y \in (0,1]$, it will work $\forall m,n$, no? 

I didn't avoid MVT to proof that statement, simply i proved it before so i didn't include the proof here.

Comment: @Daniil: Yes, uniformly continuity of $f$ implies $(f(1/n))$ Cauchy. But your implication :  "$f'$ bounded implies $f$ unifomly continuous" require MVT... so a priori you can't avoid MVT given the assumption of your exercise.

Comment: @Surb So my proof is correct? I can't see your first comment anymore where you added some details

Comment: Your proof is not correct (but the idea is correct). Your proof of $(a_n)$ is Cauchy doesn't use uniform continuity... Moreover, your proof use MVT (so your question is strange... when you said "but they apply MVT to conclude. Is it necessary ?) You also used it when you said $f'$ bounded implies $f$ Lipschitz.